# Setup SmarterMail on IIS as subdomain

Tags: email, subdomain, vps

I am surprised there is not more information out there about this. I assume it is a fairly common issue.

My situation: I have a vps that I have setup a website on (http://honeybadgertech.com/) and I would like to add email also. Preferably on a subdomain such as mail.honeybadgertech.com. I have done the basic installation of [smartermail](http://www.smartertools.com/smartermail/mail-server-software.aspx) but cant find instructions on how to configure it to run on IIS as a sub-domain. I have setup many websites in the past but I have no experience with email at all. Can anyone help me with the details of setting up smarter mail on a sub-domain? or would it just be easier to register a separate mail domain from godaddy to run the email?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so here is how I was able to get running.

1. [Install download](http://www.smartertools.com/smartermail/mail-server-software.aspx)
2. [Setup sub-domain in IIS](http://portal.smartertools.com/KB/a2352/set-up-smartermail-as-an-iis-site-iis-70.aspx)
3. Add A or CNAME Record for sub.yourdomain.com
4. Add MX Record for yourdomain.com
5. Add reverse DNS record (if possible)

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

You can make the following changes in IIS to access the mail.domain.com.

1. Start >> Administrative tools >> IIS.
2. Select SmarterMail Website.
3. Click on Bindings. Add new binding with port 80. (By Default Smartermail runs on the 9998 port)
4. In the host header value box, add mail.domain.com.
5. Click Ok.

Now, you can access the SmarterMail with http://mail.domain.com in your browser.